# React can't talk to node ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: axios

I am trying to create a React / Node app.

Inside a React component I am trying to populate a component using:

```
await axios.get('//localhost:8081/')).data;
```

Node is running and netstat shows it is listening on 8081, additionally when I test using curl, the data is returned:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/
[{"id":1,"data":"test"}]
```

However in the browser console I see:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 2):

"npm start" was running on port 3000, the server's firewall had this port open. node was running on 8081, this port was not open.

I thought the 3000 process (npm start) would talk to the 8081 process (node) directly, or something like that. But it looks like the 3000 server gives the page, then your browser talks directly to the 8081 process. Once I opened port 8081 on the firewall and changed the axios line with the server's IP it all worked.

I don't really understand why there are two processes for this.

Comment: the 3000 process packages and delivers the front end code to the browser. to do any work on the server you need to invoke the 8081 process. or use next.js and ssr.

Answer (score 1):

Check if cors is enabled on server side. Additionally check if any other process is using the port, and node process/server is actually running.

Comment: I have const cors = require('cors'); & app.use(cors()); It is running because curl works.

Comment: I'm running node on 8081 and I'm running another server on 3000 which is npm start -- does the 3000 server talk to the 8081 server, or is the request coming directly from my browser?